# Does Hibernation damage SSD if SWAP on Mech Hard Drive

Tags: ssd

I have my / and /Home on a 120GB SSD and data and SWAP are on a mechanical Hard Drive. Will using Hibernation have a negative impact on my SSD or is it OK as SWAP is not on that drive?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not damage your SSD, it is OK like this.

Comment: Thank You. I was concerned that it might lead to a lot of rewrites on the SSD but I guess this in fact is done on SWAP which is on the mechanical drive

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it would since Hibernation writes everything to ssd, it would increase writes to your ssd > reduce its life.

In real life, most modern ssd can last very long so Hibernation isnt a big problem.

if you want to tweak and optimize SSD for Ubuntu, disable Hibernation

```
sudo nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

Look for

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

yes

Change from “yes” to “no”, there are two, one for hibernation, and another one for suspend. If you have to disable them both, make sure to replace them both from yes to no.

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>


<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```

Comment: If swap is on the mechanical HDD, why would hibernation write to the SSD?